# Loop through multiple values from an array to create multiple arrays

Tags: 7

I have $host_entity which contains:

```
field_eventorganizer (Array, 1 element)
und (Array, 3 elements)
0 (Array, 1 element)
target_id (String, 2 characters ) 20
1 (Array, 1 element)
target_id (String, 4 characters ) 345
2 (Array, 1 element)
target_id (String, 2 characters ) 678
```

and the below code in which I need to create multiple arrays inside the `array('#markup'`.

```
$organisers=user_load($host_entity->field_eventorganizer['und'][0]['target_id']);
$organiser_email=$organisers->mail;
    $build['field_eventorganizer'] = array(
    '#theme' => 'registration_property_field',
    '#label' => 'Event Organiser(s)',
    '#items' => array(
        array('#markup' => l($username, 'mailto:' . $organiser_email, array('absolute' => TRUE)),),
        ),
        '#classes' => 'field field-label-inline clearfix',
    );
```

Do I need to create a foreach loop after `array('#markup' =>` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to loop the `$build` variable :)

```
// define variables
$organisers[] = "";
$organiser_email = "";
$organiser_name = "";
$email_delimiter = "; ";

// recreate the array from your example
$organisers['und'][0]['target_id'] = 20;
$organisers['und'][1]['target_id'] = 345;
$organisers['und'][2]['target_id'] = 678;

// populate $build variable
$build['field_eventorganizer'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'registration_property_field',
      '#label' => 'Event Organiser(s)2',
      '#classes' => 'field field-label-inline clearfix',
    );

// because the numbers are nested in the array, I've chosen to use `for` instead of 
// `foreach` to use $i as the iterator then rebuild what I'm looking for in the loop. I've 
// used count($organisers['und']) because the next piece of the array is the number we are
// using to load user data.

for ($i = 0; $i < count($organisers['und']); $i++) {
    // load the user object based on $i
    $organisers = user_load($host_entity->field_eventorganizer['und'][$i]['target_id']);
    // fetch loaded users email
    $organiser_email = $organisers->mail;
    // fetch loaded users name
    $organiser_name = $organisers->name;
    // populate $build variable
    $build['field_eventorganizer'][] = array(
      '#items' => array(
        array('#markup' => l($organiser_name, 'mailto:' . $organiser_email, array('absolute' => TRUE)),),
      ),
    );
}
```

Side note: Not sure if it was intentional or not, but be careful of your plurals. You are using `$organisers` and `$organiser_email` which can sometimes be missed and cause a headache.

Comment: As discussed, thanks again as always you rock! I learned tons, and would have used foreach loop instead lol Grat point about wording and plural!